# Search mysql Database using MATCH() don't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, match

There is more than ten questions in stackoverflow about this topic and I read most of them but still I can't search my DB...!!!
This is my table's structur:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE content.htmlLink(
LessonID INT NOT NULL,
LessonTitle VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
LessonContent TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
storeDate VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
fileName VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,

FOREIGN KEY(LessonID) REFERENCES `content`.`html`(id)

);";
```

and parent table :

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE content.html(
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
content TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
storeDate VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
tag1 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
tag2 VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
tag3 VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
tag4 VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
tag5 VARCHAR(32) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);";
```

There is no problem with insert information to tables.
But, now I'm trying to made a search engine for users.
I want to search if user pattern exist in `LessonContent` , so I wrote this lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content.htmllink 
        WHERE MATCH(LessonTitle,LessonContent) AGAINST('$pattern')";
$query = $conn->query($sql);

//I tried to use bind param
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content.htmllink 
        WHERE MATCH(LessonTitle,LessonContent) AGAINST('?')";
$prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
$prepare->execute( array( $pattern ) );
$fetch = $prepare->fetchAll();

//or with IN BOOLEAN MODE arg
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content.htmllink WHERE MATCH(LessonTitle,LessonContent) AGAINST('html', IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Even I checked the Query with specific pattern like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content.htmllink 
        WHERE MATCH(LessonTitle,LessonContent) AGAINST('html')";
```

But still $query is false.
Would you tell me where is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.
I searched this links:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html
[Another site](http://www.slideshare.net/KiyarashVahed/savedfiles?s_title=practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql&user_login=billkarwin)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html
[How to search MySQL database using MATCH AGAINST method that returns only rows that have a particular field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961826/how-to-search-mysql-database-using-match-against-method-that-returns-only-rows-t)
[How to make MYSQL search for minimum 3 keyword matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142585/how-to-make-mysql-search-for-minimum-3-keyword-matches)
and so many others...

Comment: what is your table engine ?

Comment: @samitha I forgot to tell Sorry, It's `InnoDB`...

Comment: Mysql older versions(InnoDB) does not support  FULL TEXT SEARCHES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnoDb` (Mysql Version 5.6) does support `FULL TEXT SEARCHES`.As you mentioned your version is bellow that it so it doesn't support

[See the link here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/02/26/myisam-vs-innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-1/)

Comment: So, I have to Alter tables with MyISAM?

Comment: Yes.IF you don't have privileges to update it to the 5.6 you have to ALTER TABLE